# The if statement inside the return statement of my presentational component is throwing an unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a presentational component called Navbar.jsx that returns another presentational component based on whether the user is authenticated or not. When I run webpack, I am getting an error saying that the "if" in my if statement is an unexpected token. You'll see the if else statement in the navbar-collapse div. Here is Navbar.jsx:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import PreAuthNavTabs from './PreAuthNavTabs';
import PostAuthNavTabs from './PostAuthNavTabs';

const Navbar = ({ activeUser, loginUser }) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
              <div className="container">
                <div className="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span className="sr-only">Toggle Navigaton</span>
                        <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <Link to="/inventory"><img className="navbar-brand" src='../../css/hello_bacsi.png'></img></Link>
                </div>
                <div className="navbar-collapse collapse">
                            {
                                if (activeUser) {
                                    return <PostAuthNavTabs activeUser={activeUser} />;
                                } else {
                                    return <PreAuthNavTabs loginUser={loginUser} />;
                                }
                            }
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    );

};

Navbar.propTypes = {
    activeUser: PropTypes.object,
    loginUser: PropTypes.func
};

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `if-else` statements in JSX. Have a look at [the relevant docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html).

---

Instead, use the ternary operator:

```
<div className="navbar-collapse collapse">
     {activeUser ?
         <PostAuthNavTabs activeUser={activeUser} /> :
         <PreAuthNavTabs loginUser={loginUser} />
     }
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know why an immediately invoked function will work in JSX, but if else statement do not?

Comment: @Mjuice JSX tags are sugar for function calls (or object literals) - it doesn't work for the same reason an `if`/`else` statement in any other function call wouldn't work - it's not an expression which returns a value, whereas an IIFE is.

Comment: So if I stuck an IIFE into my curly brackets here, and then used an If else statement inside the IIFE with a "return" call on some value, shouldn't that work?

Comment: That will work. You can define functions and call them from inside JSX.

Answer (score 3):

IIFE and ternary expressions can work in JSX because they are [Javascript expressions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-expressions); `if` statements are not.

A little modification on the example of the official doc to make it clearer: [if-else in JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html)

```
// This JSX:
<div id={if (condition) { 'msg' }}>Hello World!</div>

// Is transformed to this JS:
const props = { 
  id: if (condition) { 'msg' } // which isn't valid JavaScript
} 
const children = "Hello World!"
React.createElement("div", props, children);
```

You can play around with [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/) for some valid expressions to see how your JSX is transformed.

Comment: If I wrapped an if else chain in an IIFE and then plugged it into my jsx, would that work? I see in the React docs you linked, they use a switch statement in an IIFE, I am really having trouble understanding the difference between what is an expression and what is not.

Comment: Yes wrapping if else in IIFE would work as long as you return an element for each case. Expression's something that produces a value. See this link: http://www.2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html?m=1

Comment: Imagine you do let activeUser = if ... else ... It would not work. Swap that with IIFE it will.